# Is there a way to customize the output of git blame?

Tags: git, blame

`git log` has a nice `--format` option to specify how the output should be formatted.

But `git blame` doesn't seem to have an equivalent, although default output of `blame` is not quite human-friendly. I would like to see much less.

For example, instead of:

```
5600cab7 js/sidebar/VehicleGrid.js        (Rene Saarsoo    2009-10-08 18:55:24 +0000 127)    if (x > y) {
b5f1040c js/map/monitoring/VehicleGrid.js (Mihkel Muhkel   2010-05-31 07:20:13 +0000 128)        return x;
```

I would like to have:

```
5600cab7 Rene Saarsoo (1 year ago)     127:    if (x > y) {
b5f1040c Mihkel Muhkel (5 months ago)  128:        return x;
```

I figure that I could write a script to parse the output of `git blame --porcelain` but given the horrendous default output of `blame` I feel that somebody out there must have already done something about it.

Any ideas? Or any tips for implementing such a script?

Comment: You can always use `git gui blame <file>` :-)

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it won't work over SSH.

Comment: it would work (at least when both sides use X Window) if you enable **X11 Forwarding**... though I wouldn't recommend it because it can be slow.

Comment: You should promote your "my small link" script link below into the Edit above, took me a while to find it.

Comment: Git 2.18 (Q2 2018, 8 years later) adds a few color configuration options for `git blame`: see [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3959409/6309).

Answer (score 21):

You can use alternate output format: `git annotate` or `git blame -c`.

You can change formatting of dates with `--date=<format>` option (or `blame.date` config variable), where `<format>` is one of *relative, local, default, iso, rfc, short*.  See [git-blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) and [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) manpages for details.

Comment: Yeah, the --date option helps a bit, but it's still not nearly as good as I would like it to be. And annotate produces IMHO just an alternative ugly output :P

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo: There are GUIs for blame / annotate, one of which is `git gui blame`.

Comment: There is a nice script available [here](https://gist.github.com/ilius/7d87de079a8abdb03d09) which adds nice formatting and colors.

Comment: You can also do `--date=format:XXXXX` for even more flexible date formatting.

Answer (score 13):

Update Git 2.18 (Q2 2018): "`git blame`" learns to unhighlight uninteresting metadata from the originating commit on lines that are the same as the previous one, and also paint lines in different colors depending on the age of
the commit.

See [commit 0dc95a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dc95a4d8a71bcb0c9d0163716bd99c2d785bd10), [commit 25d5f52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25d5f52901f0d56b2e3df06b53062ee599b0403b), [commit cdc2d5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdc2d5f11f1ab931d2f39fefc6197ea1cab220a6) (24 Apr 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d24129](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d241297991c6f6ac6b1e50e52a4ae35bc431f28), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `builtin/blame`: add new coloring scheme config

> Add a config option that allows selecting the default color scheme for
> blame. The command line still takes precedence over the configuration.

[`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.18.0#git-config-blamecoloring) now reports:

> ```
> blame.coloring::
> ```

> This determines the coloring scheme to be applied to blame output.
> It can be '`repeatedLines`', '`highlightRecent`', or '`none`' which is the default.

---

> ### builtin/blame: highlight recently changed lines

> Choose a different color for dates and imitate a 'temperature cool down'
> depending upon age.
>
> Similarly to the previous patch, this offers the command line option
> '`--color-by-age`' to enable this mode and the config option
> '`color.blame.highlightrecent`' to select colors.

[The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.18.0#git-config-colorblamehighlightRecent) now adds:

> ```
> color.blame.highlightRecent
> ```

> This can be used to color the metadata of a blame line depending on age of the line.
>
> This setting should be set to a comma-separated list of color and date settings, starting and ending with a color, the dates should be set from oldest to newest.
> The metadata will be colored given the colors if the the line was introduced
> before the given timestamp, overwriting older timestamped colors.
>
> Instead of an absolute timestamp relative timestamps work as well, e.g.
> 2.weeks.ago is valid to address anything older than 2 weeks.
>
> It defaults to '`blue,12 month ago,white,1 month ago,red`', which colors
> everything older than one year blue, recent changes between one month and
> one year old are kept white, and lines introduced within the last month are
> colored red.

---

> ### `builtin/blame`: dim uninteresting metadata lines

> When using `git-blame`, lots of lines contain redundant information, for
> example in hunks that consist of multiple lines, the metadata (commit
> name, author, date) are repeated.
> A reader may not be interested in those, so offer an option to color the information that is repeated from the previous line differently.
> Traditionally, we use CYAN for lines that are less interesting than others (e.g. hunk header), so go with that.

> The command line option '`--color-lines`' will trigger the coloring of
> repeated lines, and the config option '`color.blame.colorLines`' is
> provided to select the color.
> Setting the config option doesn't imply that repeated lines are colored.

---

Note: The "`--color-lines`" and "`--color-by-age`" options of "[`git blame`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/871e42eb0996ff43a11faf47c6c05f869c4bb72c/Documentation/git-blame.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame))</sup> have been missing, which are now documented with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit 8c32856](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998) (08 Oct 2021), and [commit 38c356a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38c356aad6c9805ce766e44067c18a1894eb7d62) (01 Oct 2021) by [Bagas Sanjaya (`bagasme`)](https://github.com/bagasme).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 871e42e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/871e42eb0996ff43a11faf47c6c05f869c4bb72c), 18 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`blame`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998): document --color-* options
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Dr. Matthias St. Pierre</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Dr. Matthias St. Pierre</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bagas Sanjaya</sup>

> Commit [cdc2d5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdc2d5f11f1ab931d2f39fefc6197ea1cab220a6) ("`builtin/blame`: dim uninteresting metadata lines", 2018-04-23, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d241297991c6f6ac6b1e50e52a4ae35bc431f28) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15a486ca1dd67757cb6a3c0545dc2c6ef992bc3)) and [25d5f52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25d5f52901f0d56b2e3df06b53062ee599b0403b) ("`builtin/blame`: highlight recently changed lines", 2018-04-23, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d241297991c6f6ac6b1e50e52a4ae35bc431f28) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f15a486ca1dd67757cb6a3c0545dc2c6ef992bc3)) introduce `--color-lines` and `--color-by-age` options to [`git blame`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/git-blame.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame))</sup>, respectively.
> While both options are mentioned in usage help, they aren't documented in `git-blame(1)`.
> Document them.

`git blame` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/git-blame.txt#L14-L15):

> [--color-lines] [--color-by-age] [--progress] [--abbrev=]
> [ | --contents  | --reverse ..] [--]

`blame-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L139-L149):

> ### `--color-lines`
>
> Color line annotations in the default format differently if they come from
> the same commit as the preceding line. This makes it easier to distinguish
> code blocks introduced by different commits. The color defaults to cyan and
> can be adjusted using the `color.blame.repeatedLines` config option.
>
> ### `--color-by-age`
>
> Color line annotations depending on the age of the line in the default format.
> The `color.blame.highlightRecent` config option controls what color is used for
> each range of age.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/config/color.txt#L15-L20):

> This setting should be set to a comma-separated list of color and
> date settings, starting and ending with a color, the dates should be
> set from oldest to newest. The metadata will be colored with the
> specified colors if the line was introduced before the given
> timestamp, overwriting older timestamped colors.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/config/color.txt#L26-L29):

> It defaults to `blue,12 month ago,white,1 month ago,red`, which
> colors everything older than one year blue, recent changes between
> one month and one year old are kept white, and lines introduced
> within the last month are colored red.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8c3285613322f5b08c8a2320030f4e74b5032998/Documentation/config/color.txt#L32-L34):

> Use the specified color to colorize line annotations for
> `git blame --color-lines`, if they come from the same commit as the
> preceding line. Defaults to cyan.

---

Original answer 2010

Considering web interface like Trac or Redmine integrate `git blame` results, I suppose such a parsing has already been done.

You can see in this [Redmine Defect 3832](http://www.redmine.org/issues/3832) an example with this ruby script:

- **[`git_adapter.rb`](http://www.redmine.org/attachments/2809/0001-switched-git-blame-to-use-the-porcelain-format-p.patch)**

Comment: **gitweb** also include 'blame' (and 'blame_incremental') view, though it is by default turned off (because it is CPU hog).

Comment: It is more fun to read documentation than GitHub source (especially when the text is very long and takes time to render). First link is [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.18.0#git-config-blamecoloring) and second one is [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.18.0#git-config-colorblamehighlightRecent). And I guess by “21.8” you meant “2.18”? (I could have made the fix but I would like to know your idea first.)

Comment: @Fra yes, 2.18. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @FranklinYu I have included your links (there were not present at the time I edited this answer for Git 2.18 last June)

Answer (score 13):

Going further with [VonC's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3959409/6320039), I made a more complete scale for the `color.blame.highlightRecent` config:

```
[color "blame"]
    highlightRecent = 237, 20 month ago, 238, 19 month ago, 239, 18 month ago, 240, 17 month ago, 241, 16 month ago, 242, 15 month ago, 243, 14 month ago, 244, 13 month ago, 245, 12 month ago, 246, 11 month ago, 247, 10 month ago, 248, 9 month ago, 249, 8 month ago, 250, 7 month ago, 251, 6 month ago, 252, 5 month ago, 253, 4 month ago, 254, 3 month ago, 231, 2 month ago, 230, 1 month ago, 229, 3 weeks ago, 228, 2 weeks ago, 227, 1 week ago, 226
```

Which has a scale from 20 month ago to now (last 4 weeks with different colors):

[image]

If you improved it, comment [the gist](https://gist.github.com/BuonOmo/ce45b51d0cefe949fd0c536a4a60f000)! And star if you liked it ❤️

Answer (score 7):

For me, the -s flag works, because all I need is the SHA1 ID, after which I look up the commit for details.  A script definitely seems like overkill.  Is it possible the -s flag was unavailable a year ago?

Comment: Having used [my small script](https://github.com/nene/config/blob/master/bin/git-praise) for over a year now, I can say it was a well-spent tiny little effort. The -s flag is not enough for me - I really care about the author and date, I don't want to go digging any deeper if I can avoid it. Additionally my script produces a nice colored output.

Answer (score 4):

Since `git log` provides way more customization options for output, you can combine `git blame`, `awk`, `xargs` and `git log` to achieve what you want. E.g.

```
git --no-pager blame <filepath> -L1,+1 --porcelain | awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' | xargs git --no-pager log -1 --pretty=format:"%h - (%cd) %s - %an" --date=relative
```

This outputs something like this:

```
f8a66e80c - (5 months ago) Add gem: devise - elquimista
```

Basically what `git blame` and `awk` does above is get a full commit SHA, and `xargs` passes it to `git log` as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your .gitconfig to get relative time (n days ago etc)

```
[blame]
    date = human
```

Comment: This should be `= relative`

Comment: With that and `highlightRecent` git blame really becomes user friendly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need time for displaying, you can write jus:
git blame --date=format: [yourfilename.extension]

Note: You should not write anything after 'format:'!

Answer (score -1):

`git blame --porcelain` gives the information you need in a form that should be easy for a script to read, but is hard for a human. This would be a good place to start writing a script.