# Is there a way to let `git blame` show both names and emails?

Tags: git

`git blame` has an option `-e` which shows email but will not show name anymore. Is there a way to show both names and emails? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958977/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-output-of-git-blame

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way. You can parse output of `git blame --line-porcelain` but that requires some programming.